# Como subir ruta de foto e imagen en carpeta con php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo el siguiente formulario y estoy usando php y mysqli:

index.php

```
<?php
  include "conexion.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Alta de Producto</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("css/mycss.css");
</style>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="todo">



  <div id="contenido">
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 800px; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
        <span> <h1>Agregar Nuevo Producto</h1> </span>
        <br>
      <form action="nuevo_prod2.php" method="POST" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
        <label>Categría: </label>
        <input type="text" id="categoria_sti" name="categoria_sti"><br>

        <label>Nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre_sti" name="nombre_sti" ><br>

        <label>Precio: </label>
        <input type="text" id="preciboom" name="preciboom" ><br>

        <label>Destacado: </label>
        <input type="text" id="destacado" name="destacado" ><br>

        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
     </form>
    </div>

  </div>



</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Este es el archivo nuevo_prod2.php que procesa mi formulario

```
<?php
  include "conexion.php";
?>
<?php


    NuevoProducto($_POST['categoria_sti'], $_POST['nombre_sti'], $_POST['preciboom'], $_POST['destacado']);

    function NuevoProducto($categoria_sti, $nombre_sti, $preciboom, $destacado)
    {
        include 'conexion.php';
        $sentencia= "INSERT INTO stickerb (categoria_sti, nombre_sti, preciboom, destacado) VALUES ('".$categoria_sti."', '".$nombre_sti."', '".$preciboom."', '".$destacado."') ";
        $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al ingresar los datos".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Producto Ingresado Exitosamante!!");
    window.location.href='index.php';
</script>
```

Este es mi archivo de conexion.php

```
<?php
    $conexion= new mysqli("localhost", "root", "boom23140", "sticker1_boom");
    //Comprobar conexion
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        printf("Fallo la conexion");
    }
    else {
        //printf("Estas conectado");
    }
?>
```

Todo muy bien hasta alli, pero como puedo hacer para agregar un campo que me permita seleccionar una foto y luego procesarla para que me guarde en mi base de datos la ruta de la foto, ejemplo: que quede la foto en una carpeta y solo se guarde en la base de datos la ruta.

de que forma podría hacer esto con php y mysqli.

Saludos.

Comment: Amigo lo que necesitas  es tener otro variable en tu base de datos para guardar la dirección de la imagen                                                                              Ejemplo ===> $sentencia= "INSERT INTO stickerb (categoria_sti, nombre_sti, preciboom, destacado,ruta_imagen) VALUES ('".$categoria_sti."', '".$nombre_sti."', '".$preciboom."', '".$destacado."', '".$ruta_imagen." ";   algo así.

Comment: @Mauricio Cartagena Coria muchas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente ya tengo mi campo en la base de datos, y ya se como guardar la ruta en la base de datos, pero ahora como hago para que tambien me guarde la imagen en una carpeta que se llama categorias para que al consultarla se pueda buscar la imagen y traerla para porderla ver.

Answer (score 0):

> Bueno amigo creo que seria algo asi copiar la imagen y pasarle a otra carpeta

*en el archivo donde insertas los datos a la base de datos debes poner esto*

**Si no te funciona puede tomar una foto para poder ver mejor el codigo**

```
`$origen = $_POST['nombre_dela_imagen'];
    $destino = 'info_perfil_users/';
    if(copy($origen, $destino".jpg")) {
    echo "Se ha copiado correctamente la imagen";
    }
    else {
    echo "No se copiado la imagen correctamente";
    }`
```

Comment: no me funciono me apareció el siguiente error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '".jpg"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion2\nuevo_prod2.php on line 11

Comment: if(copy($origen, $destino / ".jpg"))  intenta con esto aver